# using methods of objects stored in stacks (javafx)

Tags: java, javafx-2

i'm relativly new to java...

i got an array of rectangles and a stack wich is filled with some of the list's Rectangles

```
int listNr;

Rectangle[] list = new Rectangle[100];
LinkedList stack = new LinkedList();

public void fillList(){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        list[i] = new Rectangle(10,10);    
    }     
}

public void fillStuff(){
    stack.add(list[listNr]);
}
```

to access a coordinate of a Rectangle from the list i would call the "getX()" method

```
list[listNr].getX();
```

this would return the x value.

but now i want to access the x-coordinate of a Rectangle throught the stack, **how do i do that?**

i dont understand why this wont work:

```
stack.peek().getX();
```

i always thought that in my case the stack[i] and the array[i] would refer to the same object, since...

```
 System.out.println("stack "+stack.peek());
 System.out.println("list "+list[listNr]);
```

would give me the same output: 
" list Rectangle@863d22 " and " stack Rectangle@863d22 "

and if i refers to the same object, shouldnt i be able to use the methods(like getters and setters) of the object? or am i making a logical error here?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Generics:

```
LinkedList<Rectangle> stack = new LinkedList<Rectangle>();
```

This tells Java that the LinkedList will contain Rectangles. If you try to insert anything that isn't a Rectangle, you will get a compile-time error. Since Java can tell (at compile time) that `stack` will only contain `Rectangle`s, it knows (at compile time) that you can call `getX()` on the result of `stack.peek()`.